# How do you link artes together?

Tags: tales-of-symphonia-hd

Some artes are able to used back-to-back to get some pretty good combo's in. What's the general rule on which artes can are able to be linked?

Do you have to use a level 1 then level 2 then level 3 of any arte? Is it the opposite? Do you have to use a level 3 to a level 3 in a different arte set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linking techs need to be done in order of level (lvl 1 -> lvl 2 -> lvl 3), and outside of the skill tree of the arte previously used (you can't link Sonic Thrust, and then follow up with Hurricane Thrust).

There are a few exceptions to this rule. The 'Super Chain' skill, available to Kratos and Zelos, ignore the standard level rule of chaining artes. The Ability Plus skill, available to Lloyd, allows the use of an extra level one arte in the chain (lvl 1 -> lvl 1 -> lvl 2 -> lvl 3).

The first portion of [this answer](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/561316-tales-of-symphonia/31579766#2) has most of this information, as well as a few other tidbits and quirks to the standard link progression.